# How to update entire table in a sql database from a table in matlab

Tags: sql, database, matlab

I have a sql database that I am connected to in matlab to load tables into my database. However, I cannot update these tables. When I run my code the updated table is appended to the end of my original table as new rows. I want to be able to update all the numbers in my matrix without manually inputing the new data using the update command in sql because my datapoints are constantly changing. I am currently connecting using a JDBC connection but the sqlwrite command does not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below update cmd?

```
update(conn,tablename,colnames,data,whereclause)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Since** Matlab **R2023a**, you can directly use the `sqlupdate` function (check https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database.odbc.connection.sqlupdate.html for more information). According to the documentation, it works for both ODBC and JDBC connections created with the `database` function.